# Why do I have an empty (but working) table index band in UITableView?

Tags: c#, iphone, xamarin.ios, uitableview

Using MonoTouch to develop my very first iPhone application for a customer, I've overridden the `UITableViewDataSource.SectionIndexTitles` function to provide a `string[]` array with what I thought would make the letters in the vertical band.

Currently I'm facing a working index band but without any characters displayed:

[image: iPhone]

(I do think the `UITableViewDataSource.SectionIndexTitles` has the native counterpart `sectionIndexTitlesForTableView`).

**My question:**

Can someone give me a hint on what I might be doing wrong here?

I do not have all A-Z characters but some characters missing, maybe this could be an issue?

Comment: I am not sure, but is your string[] array the same as an NSArray with NSString Objects? I have used it this way, and it always works - with all letters, as long as all letters are being returned by sectionIndexTitlesForTableView

Comment: Thanks @user387184 - The `string[]` is actually defined in MonoTouch so I'll have no way of changing this signature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in MonoTouch. A workaround is to create a new method in your table source class and decorate it with the `Export` attribute, passing the native ObjC method to override (`sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:`):

```
string[] sectionIndexArray;
//..
[Export ("sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:")]
public NSArray SectionTitles (UITableView tableview)
{                   
    return NSArray.FromStrings(sectionIndexArray);
}
```

Comment: @DimitrisTavlikos you are really fantastic! Once again, you helped me fast and accurate. Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score -4):

I would like to get back to my point...

can you show the way you build the returned value for sectionIndexTitlesForTableView? I just tried with SimpleSectionedTableView sample app from apple http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007318

with this code:

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    NSMutableArray *a = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:10];
    for (int i = 0; i<[regions count]; i++) {
        Region *r = [regions objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *s = r.name;
        [a addObject:s];
    }
    NSArray *ax = [NSArray arrayWithArray:a];
    return ax;


}
```

And everything works fine...

Comment: hi, just as a comment to whoever downvoted this - even though I don't know the details of MonoTouch, I prepared &tested the code sample and the comments point in the correct direction... so, the minimum one would expect as fairness is a short explanation for the downvote, also so that other readers can understand the reason - thanks

Comment: MonoTouch is something that lets you write an application in C#/.Net, which is then compiled into a native iOS application. So your ObjC answer here is not relevant to this question.